# Why I can't use pass in python if else statement when use condition in a single line

Tags: python, if-statement

I want to check if an item is in a list and if not, I want to append it to the list.

Usually I would write it:

```
if item not in list:
    list.append(item)
else:
    pass
```

However, I got to the point where I try to keep my code shorter and got to this:

```
list.append(item) if item not in list else list
```

To be fair, only *list.append(item) if item not in list* is my own creation. The *else* statement is due to insistence of PyCharm.
Now to my question: Why can't I follow up the *else* statement with *pass* but must write *list* instead. I can't wrap my head around it, nor did Google help too.

Thanks for your clarifications.

Comment: because `pass` is a no-op statement, but the trinary form of `if ... not ... else ...` expects an expression after `else`.

Comment: If you want a collection of unique values, consider a `set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between an `if` *statement* and a *conditional expression*.

When you write

```
if condition:
    this()
else:
    that()
```

you are writing a *statement*. It is an imperative construct — it *does* something. And the `else` bit is optional; if it is omitted, the statement will do nothing if the condition is not fulfilled.

The `this if condition else that` construct is an *expression*. It computes a value. It *always* has to compute a value, so the `else` bit has to be there. Using it for its side effects, for example by calling `list.append(), which doesn't return anything useful, is... not exactly wrong, but... well, it is wrong. Not technically, but philosophically.

So, when you want to compute a value, in one of two possible ways, and the whole thing fits in a line or so, use a conditional expression. If you want to do either of two things, one of which may be nothing, use an if statement.

Notice that you write

```
if temperature < 0:
    coat = thick
else:
    coat = thin
```

but

```
coat = thick if temperature < 0 else thin
```

In the first case, you have an if statement that selects which of two assignment statements to execute. In the second case, you have a single assignment statement, which uses a conditional expression to decide which value to assign.

Expressions can be used as statements (in which case their value is simply ignored), but statements have no value, and thus cannot be used as expressions.

Answer (score 2):

From docs(also provided by Pycharm):

```
pass is a null operation — when it is executed, nothing happens. It is useful as a placeholder when a statement is required syntactically, but no code needs to be executed, for example:
def f(arg): pass    # a function that does nothing (yet)
```

In python it's not allowed if you are using `ternary` operator interpretation, so in else you need to do something

so your solution is:

```
if item not in list:
    list.append(item)
```

Or use set()

```
set.add(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first snippet, the `else` statement is redundant, i.e.

```
if item not in a_list:
    list.append(item)
```

is enough and is as short and idiomatic as it can get (you might want to try sets for performance though).

In the second snippet, you're using a conditional *expression* to append to a list, which is not what those expressions are for. A conditional expression must have a value regardless of the condition, and `pass` is not a value. Use the conditional *statements* like above unless you need to compute a value based on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code even more by using the `and` operator

```python
item not in list and list.append(item)
```

It will only execute `list.append(item)` if `item not in list` returns `True`

Comment: You can also do `L.extend([i]*(i not in L))`, but it's not a coding golf competition.

Comment: Just a suggestion, as he said he wanted to keep his code short.

Comment: @bereal If it *were* golf, yours would be exactly as long as `i not in L and L.append(i)`. I don't see any advantage of yours (only disadvantages). Is there one? It's btw longer than `i in L or L.append(i)`.

Comment: @KellyBundy true, though that was not exactly my point.